# What is system_Cache_MB and How it can be cleared?

Tags: sql-server, networking, relational-database, database-administration

The value of system_Cache_MB from sys.dm_os_memory-clerks is increasing per day.

What is the way to clear it and is it included in sys.dm_os_memory_clerks??

I want to know this to calculate total memory utilization of server.Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Please read below regarding "SQL Server page life expectancy and memory bottleneck"

http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/06/sql-server-page-life-expectancy-and-memory-bottleneck.html

Comment: Don't use the snippet tool when not posting HTML/Javascript/CSS. I'd normally recommend the code tool, but that's not appropriate here either because this *isn't* code at all. It's also remarkably close to what would be described as a "link only" answer - is there not perhaps some *excerpt* from the page you're linking to that could demonstrate *why* that link is relevant here?